# users setting will not unlock with password ubuntu 17.10

Tags: users

I Go to settings users click on the padlock icon put in my administrator password as I am the only user with administrator privileges am asked for my password I enter it and it is refused

Answer (score 0):

I understand there is no problem with other programs using administrator privileges? You may try to use other user managment software like KUser (you may install it by any package manager ex. sinaptic) or try to change your user password from terminal and try again:

ROOT:
*sudo passwd*

Actual user:
*passwd*